# How to specify table mappings with Subsonic?

Tags: subsonic

If you are using Subsonic 3.0 and plan to use the SimpleRepository and POCOs...

How do you specify how to map from a POCO to a database table?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

SimpleRepository automatically creates the table definitions based on the classes you define so there's no mapping to be done.

Comment: Well what if a particular column's name is not what Subsonic is expecting?  How do you explicitly map it?

Comment: For the most part, I follow the convention of:

In the database it's like this:
column_name_is_like_this

And in my classes:
ColumnNameIsLikeThis

Comment: You should update your question with a specific example that isn't working as you expect.